# Carousel slide not sliding in chrome and mozilla

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have added a carousel slide to my page.Its working fine in internet explorer  but not in chrome and mozilla.I mean the carousel automatically slides after few seconds.It is giving the sliding effect on others but not in chrome and mozilla though the images are changing.How do i give the sliding effect for chrome too.

Here is the code:

```
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" style="margin-top:-22px; margin-left:-15px; margin-right:-15px;">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/400/" alt="slid0" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/400/" alt="slid1" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/400/" alt="slid2" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/400/" alt="slid3" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/400/" alt="slid4" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/400/" alt="slid5" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>

    </div>
```

Comment: could you mention the `scripts` that you are using too

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache of Google Chrome. I faced similar problems and they were resolved after clearing the cache.

Comment: Did it.Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna need jQuery to make it work. You can add the line

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

to your code (above the javascript for bootstrap) to add the jQuery quickly.